# text clipped at top after 18.04 upgrade

Tags: google-chrome, 18.04, text

Not sure why this is happening, but since the 18.04 upgrade, some text on Chrome web pages is being clipped at the top. It seems as if the box drawn to contain the text is slightly too short for the font displayed.

I've only noticed this in Chrome, though i can't rule out other programmes. And it's not limited to one particular website (Gmail, FB, LastPass -- and that one making it difficult to transcribe passwords).

Chrome has definitely been updated since, and the problem persists. This only started happening after the 18.04 upgrade. I've tried switching the Chrome theme to GTK+ and Classic with no change.

Has anyone else seen this? And is there a solution, or a suggestion where else to track down the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use Chrome, but I think that it might be a problem with the fonts. What happens if you install the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, which brings some extra fonts and maybe better fonts for Chrome (and also goodies for multimedia ...).

Comment: Its very noticeable when you click and drag your mouse to highlight text on a webpage. In Firefox on 18.04. 16.04 is perfect though.

Comment: This is not specific to Chrome. All webkit engines are affected, possibly all engines, so this applies to a lot of browsers. The issue is with Gnome and fonts I'm thinking. It's not specific to some users either, it applies to everyone. My guess is that it's a font issue and Canonical simply don't have any experienced web developers who reported this already. I've yet to figure out how to submit a bug report to launchpad without `ubuntu-report`, as I don't know what package is the cause for this.